# Notice (8): Indirect modification of overloaded property

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

After i upgrade my cakephp from 1.3 to 2.1. I got this error

> Notice (8): Indirect modification of overloaded property `ThreadsController::$data` has no effect

Help me...

Answer (score 1):

$this->data is only provided in the controller as BC way to read
data.  Using it to write data the way you're doing it will result in
angry PHP.  This is because of the way __get() works, in that it
returns read-only versions of the data it fetches.

You should be able to use the upgrade shell to update $this->data -->
$this->request->data.

more information read this

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html

Comment: now i get it. thnks. I got one more problem. This is an error.                Call to a member function input() on a non-object in

Comment: try like that public function input()

Comment: @vikastyagi It would be at the very least polite to reference the source when you do a straight copy/paste (especially when you're copying Mark Story). http://groups.google.com/group/cake-php/browse_thread/thread/49afb69bde427b33/9ae5c50bd48d3a2b?pli=1